# How to resize and position a circle

Tags: c++, opengl

my question is how to resize and position a circle object, ive created a door(a rectangle) and need a circle to be a door knob. Below is the code i found online to make a circle and im not familiar to what the code is doing can someone please assist me to goal is the have to knob place in the middle far left side.

```
//DOOR KNOB
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
glColor3f(SkyBlue);
for (int i = 0; i <= 180; i++){
double angle = 2* M_PI * i / 180;
double x = cos(angle);
double y = sin(angle);
glVertex3d(x, y, -0.5);
}
glEnd();

//DOOR side - FRONT Rectangle
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(White);
glVertex3f(0.1, -0.5, -0.5); // P1 Bottom Right
glVertex3f(0.1, -0.1, -0.5); // P2 Top Right
glVertex3f(-0.1, -0.1, -0.5); // P3 Top left
glVertex3f(-0.1, -0.5, -0.5); // P4 Bottom Left
glEnd();
```

//NEW CODE FROM COMMENTS

```
//DOOR KNOB
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glColor3f(SkyBlue);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i++){
        double angle = 2*  M_PI * i / 300;
        double x = cos(angle);
        double y = sin(angle);
        glVertex3d(x, y, -0.5);
    }
    glTranslatef(-0.2, -0.2, -0.5);
    glScalef(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glEnd();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a horrible way to draw a circle. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_algorithm and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: @Casey: You don't need a Bresenham algorithm to render a circle in OpenGL. Bresenham is suitable for generating all pixels for a circle. But OpenGL takes care of rasterizing, and you only need a set of points at a reasonable distance. Not saying that this is efficient, only that Bresenham is not the solution. My preferred approach is to calculate the cos/sin of the angle increment once, and then use those values to rotate the point in each step with a couple of multiplications and additions.

Comment: @KSM: In your case, you can probably simply calculate the coordinates to place/scale the circle properly. Multiply the coordinates you have right now by the desired size, and add the position. You can also look into calls like `glTranslatef` and `glScalef`. Also, if you're new, you may want to be aware that you're using legacy OpenGL, and almost all of the features you're using are marked as deprecated in more recent versions of OpenGL.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I updated my code above please take a look but this does not seem to work.

Comment: You need to specify the transformations before the vertices, and they can't be between `glBegin` and `glEnd`. Put them before `glBegin`. You may also have to use `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` so that you can revert the effect of the transformations after you're done rendering the door knob.